# Removing an item from Favorites

Tags: popup, animation

I'm building an application with 2 pages: Favorites and Browse.

I have an **`Add to Favorites`** button (a star icon that fills or unfills when the user clicks on it).

When a user clicks to remove an item in the Favorites page, I don't want the item to just disappear, so I'm thinking about providing an animation of the item leaving the screen, or showing a popup that says, `Are you sure you want to remove the item?` Should this be used only in the Favorites page, or also in the Browse page?

I'm open to other ideas that I might be missing.

Comment: Hi, can you please explain what you mean by using this in the Browse page as well? Can the user add/remove items there?

Comment: yea only there you can add but remove you can from bot favorites and browse page

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 ways you can slow down the user at this point.

One is the sanity check that you've described: when the user attempts a destructive, non-reversible operation, they get some sort of interruption asking if they're certain that they want to go ahead with that operation.

A second is that they cannot even start that operation without entering a different state first.

eBay's "Watching" list uses both of these techniques - the list must be put into the edit state before the items can be selected. Then, when the delete button is pushed, a dialogue asks "Delete [n] items. Are you sure?"